# Конструирование модели в rich domain model

Tags: c#

У меня есть сущность заказ в конструктор к ней я передаю список запчастей и список услуг. Это нормальная реализация если придется запчасти и услуги искать и вытаскивать и базы чтобы создать сущность Order? Или нужно создать Order без запчастей и услуг а потом передать Id заказа в сущности запчастей и услуг в качестве внешнего ключа? Использую Rich domain model.

Comment: если у вас какой то другой класс заполняет Order, пока сам Order сидит без заказов и услуг, то это уже вроде как не является `Rich domain model`

Comment: Вы упомянули базу и внешний ключ. Какую именно СУБД используете? И что используете для работы с БД: чистый ADO.NET или какую-то ORM?

Comment: Использую mssql и entity framework

Comment: Из вас каждое слово нужно тянуть клещами? Покажите код, определения моделей и прочее.

Comment: [Entity types with constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors) - вероятно это вам поможет.